# oracle How to group data based on value change

Tags: sql, oracle, gaps-and-islands

I've been struggling with this for a while now. I have the following table, where data about people logging in and out of the system is stored:

```
USERID       STATUSDATETIME         CHANGEDLOGGEDIN      LOGGEDIN      ENDDATETIME            STATEDURATION      SEQNO
johndoe      25-08-19 01:39:32      1                    1             25-08-19 01:39:32      0                  0
johndoe      25-08-19 01:39:32      0                    1             25-08-19 01:40:19      47                 0
johndoe      25-08-19 01:40:19      0                    1             25-08-19 01:40:26      7                  1
johndoe      25-08-19 01:40:26      0                    1             25-08-19 01:40:34      8                  2
johndoe      25-08-19 01:40:34      0                    1             25-08-19 01:40:50      16                 0
johndoe      25-08-19 01:40:50      0                    1             25-08-19 01:43:57      187                0
johndoe      25-08-19 01:43:57      1                    0             25-08-19 01:43:57      0                  1

johndoe      25-08-19 01:48:14      1                    1             25-08-19 01:48:14      0                  0
johndoe      25-08-19 01:48:14      0                    1             25-08-19 01:48:48      34                 0
johndoe      25-08-19 01:48:48      0                    1             25-08-19 01:48:53      5                  1
johndoe      25-08-19 01:48:53      0                    1             25-08-19 01:49:00      7                  2
johndoe      25-08-19 01:49:00      0                    1             25-08-19 01:49:08      8                  3
johndoe      25-08-19 01:49:08      0                    1             25-08-19 01:50:26      78                 0
johndoe      25-08-19 01:50:26      0                    1             25-08-19 01:50:33      7                  0
johndoe      25-08-19 01:50:33      1                    0             25-08-19 01:50:33      0                  1
```

What I am trying to accomplish is, based on a select ordered by userid,  statusdatetime and seqno, get the first statusdatetime, last enddatetime, sum(stateduration) for each "block" of loggedin = 1. The end result in this example would be something like this:

```
select userid, min(statusdatetime), max(enddatetime), sum(stateduration)
from login_table
group by userid,block_of_loggedin

USERID    min(STATUSDATETIME)   max(ENDDATETIME)    sum(STATEDURATION)
johndoe   25-08-19 01:39:32     25-08-19 01:43:57   265
johndoe   25-08-19 01:48:14     25-08-19 01:50:33   139
```

Being SQL not my strong suit and on top of that being a lot more used to MSSQL than Oracle, this has been giving me a pain for several days now.

I have tried using partition by, rollup, connect by and so many others and I wasn't able to accomplish anything near of what I would expect.

Any ideas on how that could be achieved?

Thank you all!

Comment: Please show us the expected results that correspond to your sample data. If I followed you correctly, we should have a record from `25-08-19 01:39:32` to `25-08-19 01:43:57`, and another from `25-08-19 01:48:14` to `25-08-19 01:50:33`

Comment: @GMB You did follow me correctly, that's precisely what I expect. The idea would be to have, in the end, something like what I showed on the second block: One line for the first "group", from 01:39:32 to 01:43:57 and another line for the second group from 01:48:14 to 01:50:33.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typical gaps-and-island problem. You can consider the following query:

```
select 
    userid,
    min(statusdatetime),
    max(enddatetime),
    sum(stateduration)
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by userid order by statusdatetime, enddatetime) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by userid, loggedin order by statusdatetime, enddatetime) rn2
    from mytable t
) x
where loggedin = 1
group by 
    userid,
    rn1 - rn2
order by 1, 2
```

This works by ranking the records of each user by date within the whole table, and comparing it to the rank for groups of records that have the same value for `loggedin`. When the difference between the ranks changes, then a new island (group) starts.

This **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ad0db9150b003d1ec9a2db7cb4b6fb00)** with your sample data returns:

```
USERID  | MIN(STATUSDATETIME) | MAX(ENDDATETIME)  | SUM(STATEDURATION)
:------ | :------------------ | :---------------- | -----------------:
johndoe | 25-08-19 01:39:32   | 25-08-19 01:43:57 |                265
johndoe | 25-08-19 01:48:14   | 25-08-19 01:50:33 |                139
```

Comment: This was way better than anything that I would've thought or designed. It worked like a charm. It is nice to see that this problem even has a name(gap-and-island). Much appreciated @GMB!

Comment: Welcome @EduardoMarques!